# Blockly text input blur

Tags: javascript, blockly

I have small problem about blockly.

I need to call some event (for example `alert('hello world')` ) when someone blurs text input.

I used `Blockly.addChangeListener`, but this function is not called when someone create blur event on text input.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask questions at SO

Comment: I do not see a blur event here https://developers.google.com/blockly/custom-blocks/defining-blocks - perhaps you can create one like here: https://code.google.com/p/blockly/source/browse/trunk/core/blockly.js?r=1637#718

Comment: Yes I know that this function don´t exist.
But i have to detect if someone end of writing for example cath if someone blur input.

I need to create function for autosave, but save only when someone doing but not typeing.

Comment: Perhaps save after an interval as most editors do

Comment: Yes one option is that call save event every x scond, but i don't know if is the beast choise.

Comment: It is likely the ONLY choice if you do not make a blur listener

Answer (score 1):

You can create an [`onchange`](https://developers.google.com/blockly/custom-blocks/defining-blocks#onchange) event for your input Block. Something like this:

```
onchange: function(event) {
  var text = Blockly.Javascript.valueToCode(this, 'textBox', Blockly.C.ORDER_ATOMIC);
  if (text == "") {
    alert("Hello world");
  } else {
    alert(text);
  }
}
```

where `this` makes reference to your input Block and `textBox` makes reference to the name that you have set to yours input box.